# Tax Rates on Canadian Zipcode Range Magento

Tags: magento, zip, alphanumeric

I want to add tax rates for Canadian Zip Code range which are alphanumeric. When I try to add tax rates it gives me invalid zipcode error. How can I add alphanumeric zip code range for tax rates?

Example is given below.

Country State   Zip/Post Code   Rate    Zip/Post is Range   Range From  Range To    default
CA          12.5    1   A0A1A0  A0A1C0
CA          65  1   A0A1E0  A0A1E0
CA          12.5    1   A0A1G0  A0A1K0
CA          65  1   A0A1L0  A0A1M0
CA          12.5    1   A0A1N0  A0A1P0
CA          65  1   A0A1R0  A0A1R0

Answer (score 0):

First, this is the ugly way to do it, the right way is to write a module that override this feature.
got to app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Tax/Rate/Form.php
Find the above:(For me it starts on line 155)

```
    $fieldset->addField('zip_from', 'text',
        array(
            'name' => 'zip_from',
            'label' => Mage::helper('tax')->__('Range From'),
            'value' => $rateObject->getZipFrom(),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'validate-digits'
        )
    );

    $fieldset->addField('zip_to', 'text',
        array(
            'name' => 'zip_to',
            'label' => Mage::helper('tax')->__('Range To'),
            'value' => $rateObject->getZipTo(),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'validate-digits'
        )
    );
```

change **validate-digits** to **required-entry**, so it becomes:

```
    $fieldset->addField('zip_from', 'text',
        array(
            'name' => 'zip_from',
            'label' => Mage::helper('tax')->__('Range From'),
            'value' => $rateObject->getZipFrom(),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'required-entry'
        )
    );

    $fieldset->addField('zip_to', 'text',
        array(
            'name' => 'zip_to',
            'label' => Mage::helper('tax')->__('Range To'),
            'value' => $rateObject->getZipTo(),
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'required-entry'
        )
    );
```

***Caution***:
Zip codes are limited to **10 characters** long (as stated in)
app/code/code/Mage/Tax/Model/Calculation/Rate.php (line74)

```
$zipFrom = (strlen($this->getZipFrom()) > 10) ? substr($this->getZipFrom(), 0, 10) : $this->getZipFrom();
$zipTo   = (strlen($this->getZipTo()) > 10) ? substr($this->getZipTo(), 0, 10) : $this->getZipTo();
```

Comment: It didn't work. I was able to save zip codes but when I edited tax rate it showed zero for both values.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/235224/#t363765

Note that the first code snippet does not allow shipping outside the US, due to the OP's requirements. He has posted followup code just after which allows international shipping.